# Word problem on selling pencils and erasers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

On Monday, Natsu sold 100 more pencils than erasers.

On Tuesday, the number of pencils he sold decreased by 10% while the number of erasers sold increased by 20%.

On Wednesday, the number of pencils sold increased by 10% and the number of erasers he sold decreased by 20% as compared to Tuesday.

Given that he sold 489 pencils and erasers on Wednesday, find the total number of pencils he sold over the 3 days.

Comment: i believe its compared to tuesday.

Comment: have you typed all numbers correct?, coz i am getting fraction answer

Answer (score 1):

On $M$ $$p,e$$

On $T$ $$p-p/10,e+e/5$$

On $W$  $$p-p/10+(p-p/10)/10,e+e/5-(e+e/5)/5$$ .

You can find p and e solving the system.
$$p=100+e$$
$$p-p/10+(p-p/10)/10+e+e/5-(e+e/5)/5=489$$

Comment: on tue , it is p-p/10

Comment: $$1/5=20/100=20%$.

Answer (score 0):

P= number of pencils and e= number of erasers.

Monday, p= 100+e

Tuesday p'= p×90%  e'= e×120%

Wednesday p"= p'×110%  e"= e'×80%

489 = p" + e"

Solve it.

489 = ( p× 90/100 ×110/100 ) + (e ×120/100 × 80/100) =  0.99p + 0.96e

Since p=100+ e,

489 = (100+e) × 0.99   + 0.96e =99 +1.95e

(489-99)/ 1.95 = e = 200

p= 100 +200 = 300

Comment: i still dont quite get it :(

Comment: When it says 10% more, you have to add 10/100 of the earlier amount to the same amount. I.e. p+ (10p/100) = 110p/100 and when it says 10% less you have to do the opposite(subtract) i.e. p-(10p/100) = 90p/100

Answer (score 0):

Let $p, e$ be the number of pencils and erasers sold on Monday, then

On Monday: $p=100+e$...(I)

On Tuesday number of pencils and erasers sold is $\frac{9p}{10}$ and $\frac{6e}{5}$

On Wednesday number of pencils and erasers sold is $\frac{99p}{100}$ and $\frac{12e}{50}$

So $\frac{99p}{100} + \frac{12e}{50}=489$...(II)

Solving (I) and (II) will give you the answer.